# Custom aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a simple table in Oracle:

```
buySell     quantity
--------------------
buy         200
sell        100
...
```

We want to get a net quantity of the table, positive if it's a net buy, negative otherwise. 
How can I achieve it in one query? If possible, a general solution (usable in other DBMS) is preferred. But if there's a superior Oracle-only solution, would appreciate it if you could share it too.

More generally a way to do custom aggregation (e.g. multiply different numbers to quantity of a record depending on values of other columns, before aggregation).

Answer (score 2):

```
Select
    Sum(Case When buySell = 'sell' then -1 else 1 end * quantity)
From
    table
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the `sell` into a negative; so multiply it by -1.

```
select sum( case when buysell = 'sell' then -1 * quantity
                 else quantity
            end ) as result
  from table
```

This should work across most SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do like.

```
select sum(case when buysell = 'buy' then quantity else 0 end ) - 
       sum(case when buysell = 'sell' then quantity else 0 end )
 from table
```